# Lagrange multiplier and solution with $i$ entry on constrained optimization.

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, convex-optimization, lagrange-multiplier

I'm reading the paper *Portfolio optimization with linear and fixed
transaction costs ([link](https://stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/papers/pdf/portfolio.pdf))*. In section 2.3 they solve for the following.
\begin{aligned}
\text{minimize} \quad & f(x)=x_i \\
\text{subject to} \quad & g(x)=(w+x)^T\Sigma (w+x)-\sigma^2
\end{aligned}

They perform the lagrangian to get the values of $x_i$. First they compute the gardients: $\nabla_x f = \lambda e_i \quad \nabla_xg=2\Sigma(w+x)$ as indicated on the paper. I believe they leave $\lambda$ in the first equation because they use that part as the second term of the lagrange multiplier. However, what is not clear to me how they go to the result of $x_i$.

$$
x_i = \sigma \sqrt{(\Sigma^{-1})_{ii}}-w_i
$$

For the lagrange multiplier we should have $\mathcal {L}(x,\lambda )=f(x)-\lambda g(x)$, I believe they just changed to $\mathcal {L}(x,\lambda )=g(x)-\lambda f(x)$ because for some reason it should be the same (correct me if I'm wrong please). Then $\nabla _{x,\lambda }{\mathcal {L}}(x,\lambda )=0$, the gradient with respect to $\lambda$ does actually nothing and the gradient w.r.t. $x$ gives us $\lambda e_i-2\Sigma(w+x)=0$, thus they have 2 unknowns ($x$ and $\lambda$) and 1 equation only:

\begin{aligned}
\lambda e_i-2\Sigma(w+x)=0
\end{aligned}

I've tried other things, but with no success, and I'm pretty sure that I'm missing something simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\Sigma$ invertible, from

$$
\mathcal{L}(x,\lambda) = x_i -\lambda g(x)
$$

we have

$$
\nabla_x \mathcal{L} = e_i-2\lambda\Sigma(w+x)=0
$$

and then

$$
w+x=\frac{1}{2\lambda}\Sigma^{-1} e_i
$$

now substituting into $g(x)=0$ we have

$$
\frac{1}{4\lambda^2}\left(e_i^T\Sigma^{-1}e_i\right) = \sigma^2
$$

and then

$$
2\lambda = \frac{1}{\sigma}\sqrt{\left(e_i^T\Sigma^{-1}e_i\right)}
$$

hence

$$
w+x = \frac{\sigma}{\sqrt{\left(e_i^T\Sigma^{-1}e_i\right)}}\Sigma^{-1} e_i
$$

NOTE

Here $\left(e_i^T\Sigma^{-1}e_i\right) = \left(\Sigma^{-1}\right)_{i,i}$

Comment: Thanks a lot @Cesareo I learned something today thanks to you. It's the first time for me playing around with $e_i$s in equations. Once you see it, seems kind of obvious. =D